# UITableView Cells drawing on top of each other when I implement heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a new iOS project that uses UITableView.  When I implement heightForRowAtIndexPath, the cells all draw on top of each other as shown in the screen shot.

[image: cells on top of each other]

If I do not implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath routine, the cells draw normally (even though they are not exactly the right height).  Implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath triggers the overdraw behavior.

I've implemented tables and cells many times before and not seen this problem.  Two new things for me in this project compared to my previous ones are:

1. I started from the UIView template and it gave me a storyboard as the root view.  The view that exhibits the problem is a non-storyboard view controller.  I have always had a XIB as the root before.  I don't know if or how this ties into this.
2. This project has size classes enabled, where before I've always just used a iPhone or iPad targeted project.

I'll attach my code even though it is boring:

```
    -(float) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier=@"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell title";
    return cell;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: someone below mentioned that this is not the screen shot of the code given and that's true.  I will attach that screen shot - this screenshot is taken in the simulator with me having pulled the table down some, the line is at the very top of the table.  It's kind of hard to catch with the cells allocated this way.  Someone else mentioned that it looks like the cell height is 0, and I believe that to be true.  I just don't know how it gets from 44 to 0, and I don't know how to check it.  The cell's bounds/height is 44 when I allocate it (I know that via some debugging code I put in).

I also edited the code to note that I called initWithStyle per a suggestion - that had no effect.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: It seems like the table view is getting height 0 from delegate object

Comment: Given the cell in the image, the code in your question isn't the actual code. Hard to help without seeing the real code.

Comment: you should also use `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` when creating new cells.

Comment: And define the return type as `CGFloat` not as a `float`, that could actually be a big problem.

Comment: The label seems to be children of one cell and I think you have not init constraints. So when cellHeight is called view is going to layout subviews but there is no constraints. It looks like this in your image

Comment: "And define the return type as CGFloat not as a float, that could actually be a big problem"   I would have bet money that CGFloat was float but obviously not.  Searching shows that it might be a float or a double, depending on your platform.  I am now humbled.  @Sulthan If you'll put this in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @NedZepplin Even if `CGFloat` was always a `float`, you really need to ensure you use same type when defining methods. Don't just substitute different types for no reason.

Comment: @NedZepplin I've added an answer with an explanation for the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct return type for method `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is `CGFloat`. `CGFloat` is the main type for both Core Graphics and UIKit (CocoaTouch). `CGFloat` *is not* `float`. `CGFloat` is a type that becomes either `float` or `double` (32 bits or 64 bits) depending on processor architecture.

Now the problem will appear only if you are running on a 64 bit architecture (`CGFloat` is `double`). Your method will be returning a 32bit floating point number (declared as returning `float`) but the caller will be reading 64 bits from the stack (in protocol the method is declared as returning `CGFloat`). This situation is undefined and can result in multiple behaviors. In your case the resulting 64 bit number is very small (not zero but a decimal number close to zero) therefore the cells will overlap.

Always match types from function/method declarations.

Comment: Hey, I am returning row height as CGFloat(200) but still my images overlap. Is there something very obvious I am missing?

Comment: I registered my cell in viewDidLoad
self.menuTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
cellForRowAt indexPath method returns cell declared as let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
and row height as mentioned above.

Comment: @AsthaGupta Please ask a question with a full reproducible example. Comments are not for asking questions.

Comment: Sure. Posted my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890828/uibutton-s-and-uiimageview-s-are-overlapping-in-uitableviewcell-swift